# Is there a PowerPoint Interop property that describes the Monitor to Show On

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint

Does anyone know of a PowerPoint Interop property that describes the Monitor that the PowerPoint SlideShow will display on in Full Screen?

For instance, I can ascertain if the SlideShow is to be played in Full Screen with the following property:

```
Application.ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.IsFullScreen
```

I figure I could get the HWND from SlideShowWindow.HWND or its position and obtain it from there, but would prefer a more elegant approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\PowerPoint\Options\DisplayMonitor

It changes as you change monitor setting in PPT.  On my system, this value indicates the second monitor:

\.\DISPLAY2

And this the first:

\.\DISPLAY1\Monitor0

Comment: I see the logic in having this property in the registry - more often than not PPT users will want to display on the same monitor.

Comment: True.  And more generally, some properties are application-level (ie, apply to all presentations), some are presentation-level.